# jquery fadeOut not working when callback used

Tags: jquery, callback, fadein, fadeout

I have a div that is fades in with a callback which works:

```
div.fadeIn(600, function(){
    sidenote(nlevel);
});
```

At some other point though this div may need to fade out again.

```
div.fadeOut(500);
```

This happens from another function called from an onclick event.

Normally I can get this to work.  It just seems when I use a callback I can't. (It happened elsewhere, when I removed the callback on that one it worked fine.  I cannot do that here)

Thanks

Comment: provide a jsfiddle which replicate your issue, if you can replicate it...

Comment: check console for error and i think there is some problem in sidenote() function

Comment: Exactly not getting what ur supposed to do ???

Comment: what's happened if you comment the line sidenote(level); and add an alert to your function? Are you sure that div is well defined? Also check the console like Mohammad said

Comment: Hey guys,

This has worked out very strangely. There was nothing in the console. I commented out the function call and it started working. I uncommented the function call and it continued to work!

Who knows? Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Are u looking for something like this ??

Have a look at this  [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9afaF/6/)

```
$(".story1").fadeIn("50", function () {

    $(".story2").fadeOut("100");
});
```